# Should I worry about plaster walls in bathroom?

Tags: walls, plaster

I just moved in to a new house, which has plaster walls. I was told that the owners never took a shower, due to worry over the walls. There is tile all over the walls, but I still wonder if I should worry about using the shower?

Comment: Plaster or plasterboard (also called wallboard or drywall)? Plaster is rarely used in new homes in the US.

Comment: Also, when was the house built and what is the overall quality of construction?